# Adjective pertaining to 'rainforest' or similar

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for the adjective to describe that something *is* a rainforest, or similar (such as a forest, jungle, woodland.)

For instance, I am not looking for adjectives like 'green' or 'leafy,' rather an adjective to describe a jungle in the way that <strike>apine</strike> apian is too a bee, or alpine is to high mountains.

For example,

> The _____ nature of his front lawn meant that he received few visitors

Comment: Apparently he has no walkway to his door; it seems you are saying that if he did have visitors, they would have worn down a path through the grass. if he has let it grow long, perhaps it is _untamed_, _overgrown_, or at least _unkempt_ . Potential visitors might find it _daunting_, or even _impenetrable_.   And maybe he mows his lawn, and waters it abundantly, making it as _lush_ as a rainforest. Yet it has nary a footprint on it—it is as _pristine_ and _undisturbed_ as a remote, _unexplored_ rainforest.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comprehensive and well explained help, but alas the example was just an example, so that isn't quite right. Thank you for taking the time though. @BrianHitchcock

Comment: A front lawn has grass, and grass can become untamed etc. It doesn't normally have many trees, so your sentence is a slightly misguided example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jungly

jungle-like

Or if you specifically want to refer to trees then

arboraceous

arborial

Comment: Thank you very much, I never thought of searching for an adjective relating to trees, *arboraceous* was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: *Jungly*? You do realize that some rainforests are not jungles, right? The Olympic Peninsula of Washington State is a rainforest.

Comment: @Robusto - I was merely answering the question: "I am looking for the adjective to describe that something is a rainforest, or similar (such as a **forest**, **jungle**, woodland.)". I think I covered both options.

Answer (score 5):

What's wrong with *rainforest*?

> The rainforest in his front yard meant that he received few visitors.

There's nothing wrong with a little hyperbole every now and then – I think that will likely read better than:

> The «*adj*.» *nature* of his front lawn...

(unless you were trying to make a deliberate pun on the word *nature*?)

Another noun you could use is *zareba*, which means “a protective enclosure of thorny bushes,” but has been used figuratively in [literature](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Clicking_of_Cuthbert/Chapter_1):

> *Vladimir Brusiloff had permitted his face to become almost entirely concealed behind a dense **zareba** of hair, but his eyes were visible through the undergrowth*...

Comment: Thank you and +1 for your answer, it's not exactly what I was looking for but still it is very good and much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

"The **amazonian** nature of his front lawn meant that he received few visitors.

> - ["amazonian"](http://www.yourdictionary.com/amazonian) - Having to do with the Amazon River in South America, and its surrounding region.

Answer (score 2):

"Silvan/sylvan" means of woods or forests.  Only example I can think of now is Tolkien's Silvan Elves (elves of the forest). It has a somewhat poetic or archaic flavor.

The Cambridge online offers the following as "related" words: afforestation   brushwood   coppice   copse   fell   forested   forester   glade   grove   jungle   logger   logging   logjam   old growth   rainforest   reafforest   spinney   the timberline   tropical rainforest   wooded

BTW, your bee thing is "apian".

Comment: Thank you for your answer, +1, and yeah the apine/apian thing was a typo, but thanks, I corrected it.